# How can i run Laravel Queue only once?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-queue

I used laravel 5.1 Queue for my background function with async.
But i want to run that function for only 1 time. If that function fail, i want to do other process. 
How can i detect my job is failed or not?
Am i doing right or wrong ? What should i change?
ps: I'm beginner. I used like this in my controller.

```
$job = new myjob($var1, $var2);
$this->dispatch($job);
$job->release();
if ($job->attempts() >= 1)
{
    $job->delete();
    //will do other process
}
```

Comment: If you want to wait for the job and only **then** do another — why would you run it async in the first place?

Comment: I will do other process only when my job fail. And i use job as background function. Because that function have lots of curl and database process. I need to wait at least 7 sec to finish that. That's why i use job.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `--tries` parameter with `1` value, for example:

```
php artisan queue:work --tries=1
```

This will run each task only once and won't repeat it in case of failure.

Comment: I can't use console on my hosting. Can't i do it in controller ?

Answer (score 3):

if you have trouble accessing the console, you can define tries in the controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

class ProcessPodcast implements ShouldQueue
{
    /**
     * The number of times the job may be attempted.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $tries = 5;
}
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#max-job-attempts-and-timeout

And based on what you want to achieved, I suggest you use the Queued Event Listener.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/events#queued-event-listeners

I hope that help :)